# API returns JSONObjects instead of an array on Retrofit + Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit, spotify

I'm currently trying to implement a Spotify API endpoint with Retrofit on Android, and I've been dealing with this problem for a little while now. Unlike most APIs, Spotify's JSON response is just a single JSONObject with others nested inside. Of course, Retrofit gives me a "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT" error. Does anyone know a solution? Here is some of the relevant code:

**OnActivityResult** (After Spotify Authentication)

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        // Check if result comes from the correct activity
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            final AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);

            switch (response.getType()) {
                // Response was successful and contains auth token
                case TOKEN:
                    // Handle successful response
                    SpotifyApi api = new SpotifyApi();

                    api.setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken());

                    SpotifyService spotify = api.getService();

                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + response.getAccessToken())
                                    .build();
                            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                        }
                    }).build();

                    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .client(client)
                            .baseUrl("https://api.spotify.com/")
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

                    SpotifyPlayerApi spotifyPlayerApi = retrofit.create(SpotifyPlayerApi.class);

                    Call<List<CurrentlyPlaying>> call = spotifyPlayerApi.getCurrentlyPlaying();
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CurrentlyPlaying>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<List<CurrentlyPlaying>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<CurrentlyPlaying>> response) {
                            if(!response.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                testResult.setText("Code: " + response.code() + ", " + response.message());
                                return;
                            }

                            for(CurrentlyPlaying currentlyPlaying : response.body())
                            {
                                testResult.setText(currentlyPlaying.getImageUrl());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<CurrentlyPlaying>> call, Throwable t) {
                            testResult.setText(t.getMessage());
                        }
                    });


                    //List<Tracks> recommendations = spotify.getRecommendations(//).tracks;
                    /** ^ Parameter 'Map' for 'getRecommendations' = String: "seed_track", Object: "TRACK ID" (whatever's currently playing) **/
                    break;

                // Auth flow returned an error
                case ERROR:
                    // Handle error response
                    break;

                // Most likely auth flow was cancelled
                default:
                    // Handle other cases
            }
        }
```

**Class For Desired DataType**

```
public class CurrentlyPlaying {
    @SerializedName("/item/id")
    private String songId;

    @SerializedName("/item/images/url")
    private String imageUrl;

    public String getSongId() {
        return songId;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
}
```

**API Interface**

```
public interface SpotifyPlayerApi {
    @GET("v1/me/player/currently-playing")
    Call<List<CurrentlyPlaying>> getCurrentlyPlaying();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check out this.. https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/get-the-users-currently-playing-track/. On the right hand side, you will JSON response. Based on that you need to program...

Comment: why do you expect a `List` of currently playing items?

Comment: @njzk2 I was following a tutorial. I only expect one object, but it should still work.

Comment: @Ramesh_D Yeah, I see the json response. It shows how the API returns a single json object, information I already had. That doesn't help me.

Comment: If the API returns an object but you ask for a list, that's not going to work. Jakir Hossain's answer seems right, if a bit verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify your interface look like..

```
 public interface SpotifyPlayerApi {
 @GET("v1/me/player/currently-playing")
 Call<APiResponse> getCurrentlyPlaying();
 }
```

**and add the following model classes**, hope it solves your problem. to create pojo I use [this](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) you can try it by yourself.

```
public class APiResponse{
private String currently_playing_type;

private Item item;

private Context context;

private String is_playing;

private String progress_ms;

private String timestamp;

public String getCurrently_playing_type ()
{
    return currently_playing_type;
}

public void setCurrently_playing_type (String currently_playing_type)
{
    this.currently_playing_type = currently_playing_type;
}

public Item getItem ()
{
    return item;
}

public void setItem (Item item)
{
    this.item = item;
}

public Context getContext ()
{
    return context;
}

public void setContext (Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

public String getIs_playing ()
{
    return is_playing;
}

public void setIs_playing (String is_playing)
{
    this.is_playing = is_playing;
}

public String getProgress_ms ()
{
    return progress_ms;
}

public void setProgress_ms (String progress_ms)
{
    this.progress_ms = progress_ms;
}

public String getTimestamp ()
{
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp (String timestamp){
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
 }
}
```

**Item Model**

```
public class Item{
private String disc_number;

private Album album;

private String[] available_markets;

private String type;

private External_ids external_ids;

private String uri;

private String duration_ms;

private String explicit;

private Artists[] artists;

private String preview_url;

private String popularity;

private String name;

private String track_number;

private String href;

private String id;

private External_urls external_urls;

public String getDisc_number ()
{
    return disc_number;
}

public void setDisc_number (String disc_number)
{
    this.disc_number = disc_number;
}

public Album getAlbum ()
{
    return album;
}

public void setAlbum (Album album)
{
    this.album = album;
}

public String[] getAvailable_markets ()
{
    return available_markets;
}

public void setAvailable_markets (String[] available_markets)
{
    this.available_markets = available_markets;
}

public String getType ()
{
    return type;
}

public void setType (String type)
{
    this.type = type;
}

public External_ids getExternal_ids ()
{
    return external_ids;
}

public void setExternal_ids (External_ids external_ids)
{
    this.external_ids = external_ids;
}

public String getUri ()
{
    return uri;
}

public void setUri (String uri)
{
    this.uri = uri;
}

public String getDuration_ms ()
{
    return duration_ms;
}

public void setDuration_ms (String duration_ms)
{
    this.duration_ms = duration_ms;
}

public String getExplicit ()
{
    return explicit;
}

public void setExplicit (String explicit)
{
    this.explicit = explicit;
}

public Artists[] getArtists ()
{
    return artists;
}

public void setArtists (Artists[] artists)
{
    this.artists = artists;
}

public String getPreview_url ()
{
    return preview_url;
}

public void setPreview_url (String preview_url)
{
    this.preview_url = preview_url;
}

public String getPopularity ()
{
    return popularity;
}

public void setPopularity (String popularity)
{
    this.popularity = popularity;
}

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getTrack_number ()
{
    return track_number;
}

public void setTrack_number (String track_number)
{
    this.track_number = track_number;
}

public String getHref ()
{
    return href;
}

public void setHref (String href)
{
    this.href = href;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public External_urls getExternal_urls ()
{
    return external_urls;
}

public void setExternal_urls (External_urls external_urls)
{
    this.external_urls = external_urls;
}
}
```

**External_urls Model**

```
public class External_urls{
private String spotify;

public String getSpotify ()
{
    return spotify;
}

public void setSpotify (String spotify)
{
    this.spotify = spotify;
}

}
```

**External_ids Model**

```
public class External_ids{
private String isrc;

public String getIsrc ()
{
    return isrc;
}

public void setIsrc (String isrc)
{
    this.isrc = isrc;
}

}
```

**Artists Model**

```
public class Artists{
private String name;

private String href;

private String id;

private String type;

private External_urls external_urls;

private String uri;

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getHref ()
{
    return href;
}

public void setHref (String href)
{
    this.href = href;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getType ()
{
    return type;
}

public void setType (String type)
{
    this.type = type;
}

public External_urls getExternal_urls ()
{
    return external_urls;
}

public void setExternal_urls (External_urls external_urls)
{
    this.external_urls = external_urls;
}

public String getUri ()
{
    return uri;
}

public void setUri (String uri)
{
    this.uri = uri;
}
}
```

**Album Model**

```
public class Album{
private Images[] images;

private String name;

private String album_type;

private String href;

private String id;

private String type;

private External_urls external_urls;

private String uri;

public Images[] getImages ()
{
    return images;
}

public void setImages (Images[] images)
{
    this.images = images;
}

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAlbum_type ()
{
    return album_type;
}

public void setAlbum_type (String album_type)
{
    this.album_type = album_type;
}

public String getHref ()
{
    return href;
}

public void setHref (String href)
{
    this.href = href;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getType ()
{
    return type;
}

public void setType (String type)
{
    this.type = type;
}

public External_urls getExternal_urls ()
{
    return external_urls;
}

public void setExternal_urls (External_urls external_urls)
{
    this.external_urls = external_urls;
}

public String getUri ()
{
    return uri;
}

public void setUri (String uri)
{
    this.uri = uri;
}

}
```

**Images Model**

```
public class Images{
private String width;

private String url;

private String height;

public String getWidth ()
{
    return width;
}

public void setWidth (String width)
{
    this.width = width;
}

public String getUrl ()
{
    return url;
}

public void setUrl (String url)
{
    this.url = url;
}

public String getHeight ()
{
    return height;
}

public void setHeight (String height)
{
    this.height = height;
}

}
```

**Context Model**

```
public class Context{
private String href;

private String type;

private External_urls external_urls;

private String uri;

public String getHref ()
{
    return href;
}

public void setHref (String href)
{
    this.href = href;
}

public String getType ()
{
    return type;
}

public void setType (String type)
{
    this.type = type;
}

public External_urls getExternal_urls ()
{
    return external_urls;
}

public void setExternal_urls (External_urls external_urls)
{
    this.external_urls = external_urls;
}

public String getUri ()
{
    return uri;
}

public void setUri (String uri)
{
    this.uri = uri;
}
}
```

Comment: This does look very good explanation. Dude Jakir hossain done very good job i think..

Comment: Thanks, I found out through a different tutorial that this was actually what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

SerializedName should be the name of the field itself, not the complete path,
Try changing your object class to this:

```
   public class CurrentlyPlaying {
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private String songId;

        @SerializedName("url")
        @Expose
        private String imageUrl;

        public String getSongId() {
            return songId;
        }

        public String getImageUrl() {
            return imageUrl;
        }
    }
```

`@Expose` is used to decide whether the variable will be exposed for Serialisation and Deserialisation, or not. [Here's](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) the documentation of `@Expose`